# Verify contents - do not allow user to enter - give invalid data report

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a program to do following steps:

- When at cell M2, check the contents of all the cells before column
  M in same row
- In case any of the cells before column M in same row is empty, do
  not allow user to enter any value in cell M2. RAther given a message
  to user about empty data.
- Creates a report in cell N2 of the missing data's (The first row of
  excel is having headings of data contained in columns)

Problems encountered till now:
Indefinite loop - i think when clearing contents loop is triggered again that is causing this problem

I am not sure if the concatenate code is good or not.

### Program below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$M$2" Then    
MsgBox "1"    
Call MyMacro    
End If    
End Sub


Sub MyMacro()

'If [OR(ISBLANK(A2:L2))] Then
If ISBLANK(A2) Then
MsgBox "2"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = N2.Value + A1.Value
'Range("M2").ClearContents
'MsgBox "3"

'this the message that pops up if any cell in the range is blank
End If

End Sub
```

---

Thank you for your response in advance...

Comment: Do you want this for row 2 only, or for multiple rows?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will

1. test for blanks (true blanks) in `A2:L2` when `M2` is changed
2. Turn `Events` off, to avoiding reloading the code if `N2` is used
3. dump these offending cell range in `N12` is there blanks

**code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
If Intersect(Target, Range("M2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With Application
.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("A2:L2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "blank cells in " & rng1.Address(0, 0), vbCritical, "User entry in M2 removed"   
[n2] = rng1.Address
[m2].Clear
End If
.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to run this on a worksheet_Selectionchange event so you can catch it before any value is entered? Also you currently still let the value persist in M2, don't you?

Comment: On (1) but you might select the entire row, or sheet (2) Good point - I will update for that

Comment: I'd run `if target.cells.count=1 and not intersect(target,range("M2")) is nothing then`

Comment: I still prefer wiping the M2 cell rather than capturing the selection (I have added wiping now post your comment). The `Change` event captures code driven changes `Select` is unlikely to (unless the coding is poor). Plus a continuous `Change` will be less intense in the background to an ongoing `Select`

Answer (score 1):

Another option,which doesn't use macros, is to use data validation in column M, with the custom formula

`=counta(A2:L2)=12`

and the custom Error message "Blank cells in columns A through L".

This of course doesn't give you the missing cells, but you could get the first one with this array formula (enter with ctrl+Shift+enter)

`=IFERROR(ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(TRUE,A2:L2="",0)),"")`

Comment: The `Data Validation` is a good alternative if further coding from a `M2` change isn't needed.